# spark.sql in pyspark - Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

I have an issue with pyspark.sql as I try to perform a simple SQL query, but I see the following error:

> AnalysisException: 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient;'

The code that initially reads the Hive table works properly:

> df =
> spark.read.csv("hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/creditfraud/creditscoring.csv",
> header=True, sep=',', inferSchema=True) df.printSchema()

But as soon as I run spark.sql I encounter some troubles:

> df.createOrReplaceTempView("CreditTempTable")
>
> df1 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM CreditTempTable LIMIT 10") df1.show()

Hive 2.3.5 works normally and I can see the tables and run SQL code in it, so I believe that the issue comes from the Spark and Linux configuration files, which are the following:

spark-defaults.conf:

> spark.sql.hive.metastore.version 2.3.0
>
> spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars
> /usr/local/hive/lib/*:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/*

.bashrc configuration file:

> ### Set HIVE_HOME export
>
> HIVE_HOME=/usr/local/hive
> export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hive/conf
> PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
> export PATH
> export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hive/lib/*
>
> ## Set Spark vars
>
> export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark
> PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
> export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 export
> PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter export
> PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"

I would really appreciate if you could help me figuring out where the issue is coming from.

Comment: are you able to solve this ?

Comment: any solution on this error?